# Programming a simple object oriented graph in C++

Tags: c++, oop, data-structures, stl

I am really trying to be a better programmer, and to make more modular, organized code.

As an exercise, I was trying to make a very simple `Graph` class in C++ with `STL`. In the code below, my `Node` object does not compile [because the commented line results in a reference to a reference in `STL`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155142/why-do-i-get-an-error-in-forming-reference-to-reference-type-map).

```
#include <set>

class KeyComparable
{
public:
  int key;
};

bool operator <(const KeyComparable & lhs, const KeyComparable & rhs)
{
  return lhs.key < rhs.key;
}

class Node : public KeyComparable
{
public:
  // the following line prevents compilation
  // std::set<Node &> adjacent;
};
```

I would like to store the edges in a `set` (by `key`) because it allows fast removal of edges by key. If I were to store `list<Node*>`, that would work fine, but it wouldn't allow fast deletion by `key`.

If I use `std::set<Node>`, changes made through an edge will only change the local copy (not actually the adjacent `Node`). If I use `std::set<Node*>`, I don't believe the `<` operator will work because it will operate on the pointers themselves, and not the memory they index.

I considered wrapping references or pointers in another class, possibly my KeyComparable class (according to the linked page, this is how boost handles it).

Alternatively, I could store the `std::list<Node*>` and a `std::map<int, iterator>' of locations in the`std::list`. I'm not sure if the iterators will stay valid as I change the list.

Ages ago, everything here would just be pointers and I'd handle all the data structures manually. But I'd really like to stop programming `C`-style in every language I use, and actually become a good programmer.

What do you think is the **best** way to handle this problem? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you have deduced, you can't store references in STL containers because one of the requirements of items stored is that they be assignable. It's same reason why you can't store arrays in STL containers. You also can't overload operators without at least one being a user-defined type, which makes it appear that you can't do custom comparisons if you store pointers in an STL class...

However, you can still use `std::set` with pointers if you give `set` a custom comparer functor:

```
struct NodePtrCompare {
    bool operator()(const Node* left, const Node* right) const { 
        return left->key < right->key;
    }
};

std::set<Node*, NodePtrCompare> adjacent;
```

And you still get fast removals by `key` like you want.

Comment: +1 Good answer. Is there any additional benefit to wrapping the comparison function in a struct (aside from the nicer syntax than function pointers)?

Comment: @Oliver not that I know of really, it's just the only way to do it in this case. I would prefer having globally accessible `operator<` though when you can, because it makes instances comparable without having to instantiate a `struct`.